# SwiftUI: upload multiple images to Firebase

Tags: firebase, swiftui, firebase-storage

Goal: upload 3 images from SwiftUI app to Firebase, with different URL for each.

Problem: I only managed to upload 1.

What I have tried (but didn't work)....
:

```
storagePostRef.putData(image1, image2, image3, metadata: metadata) { (storageMetadata, error) in
```

Full function bellow:

```
static func savePostPhoto(
    
    
    //id
    userId: String,
    
    image1: Data,
    image2: Data,
    image3: Data,
    
   // imagesArray : [Data],


    metadata: StorageMetadata,
    storagePostRef: StorageReference,
    onSuccess: @escaping() -> Void,
    onError: @escaping(_ errorMessage: String) -> Void)

  {
    
    let arrayOfImages : [Data] = [image1, image2, image3]

        
    //image storage
    storagePostRef.putData(image1, metadata: metadata) { (storageMetadata, error) in
        
          if error != nil {
              onError(error!.localizedDescription)
              return
          }
        
        //image URL

        storagePostRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            
            let image1 = url?.absoluteString
            let image2 = url?.absoluteString
            let image3 = url?.absoluteString

   
        }
    }
    


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call to `putData` stores a single image, in the location that you call `putData` on.

So if you want to store three separate images, you'll have to call `putData` on three difference `StorageReference` objects. To then get the three download URLs, you call `downloadURL` on each of the three `StorageReference` objects too.

```
storagePostRef1.putData(image1, metadata: metadata) { (storageMetadata, error) in
  storagePostRef1.downloadURL { (url1, error) in
    let image1 = url?.absoluteString  storagePostRef2.putData(image2, metadata: metadata) { (storageMetadata, error) in
      storagePostRef2.downloadURL { (url2, error) in
        storagePostRef3.putData(image3, metadata: metadata) { (storageMetadata, error) in
          storagePostRef3.downloadURL { (url3, error) in
```

You can probably clean this up a bit, by creating your own helper function that handles the calls to `putData` and `downloadUrl` with a single closure/callback.

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well.

```
 var photoArrayModel = PhotoArrayModel(photoArray: [])
 let userPhotosFirstoreRef = self.ref.document(uid)
 imagesData.enumerated().forEach { index, imageData in
                let userPhotosStorageRef = self.storageRoot.child("user_photos").child(uid).child("image_\(index)")
                userPhotosStorageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { metaData, error in
                    if error != nil {
                        promise(.failure(.uploadingPhoto))
                    }
                    userPhotosStorageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
                        if error != nil {
                            promise(.failure(.uploadingPhoto))
                        }
                        guard let urlString = url?.absoluteString else { return promise(.failure(.uploadingPhoto))}
                        let photo = PhotoModel(ownerID: uid, imageURL: urlString, timeStamp: Date().millisecondsSince1970)
                        photoArrayModel.photoArray.append(photo)
                        
                        if photoArrayModel.photoArray.count == imagesData.count {
                            do {
                                try userPhotosFirstoreRef.setData(from: photoArrayModel.self)
                                promise(.success(()))
                            } catch {
                                promise(.failure(.uploadingPhoto))
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```