# SwiftUI 3.0 Upload multiple images at once to Firebase for a feed

Tags: firebase, image, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, upload

at present my viewmodel can upload one image but i will like the ability to upload multiple images at once, I have coded that in the image picker just having problems with my upload class. Below is my code:

```
struct PeopleView: View {
    class MainFeedUploadViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @ObservedObject var authViewModel = AuthViewModel()
        func uploadfeedPost(caption: String, myhashtags: String, image: UIImage) {
            
            if let user = authViewModel.currentUser {
                ImageUploader.upLoadImage(image: image, type: .feed) { imageUrl in
                    let data = [
                        "caption": caption,
                        "timestamp": Timestamp(date: Date()),
                        "likes": 0,
                        "imageUrl": imageUrl,   // here is where i have my issue
                        "ownerUid": user.id ?? "",
                        "ownerImageUrl": user.profileImageUrl,
                        "ownerUsername": user.username
                    ] as [String : Any]
                    
                    COLLECTION_FEEDS.addDocument(data: data) { _ in
                        print("DEBUG: Uploaded feed")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have included the code for the image uploader:

```
struct ImageUploader {
    static func upLoadImage(image: UIImage, type: UploadType, completion: @escaping(String) -> Void) {
        guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else { return }
        let ref = type.filePath
        
        ref.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { _, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Debug: Failed to upload image with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            ref.downloadURL { imageUrl, _ in
                guard let imageUrl = imageUrl?.absoluteString else {
                    return
                }
                completion(imageUrl)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried making the UIImage an array with no luck.

Comment: Can you explain what the issue is? You have a line that says "here is where i have my issue", but it's not clear what that issue *is*. You have variables and types referenced in your code that aren't included, so unless you explain the issue in detail, since no one can run your code, it'll be very challenging to suggest a solution.

Comment: @jnpdx This class i have here only uploads one picture at a time to firebase, i tried putting the imageUrl in an array but xcode screamed back, thats why i wrote thats where i have an issue, 3 views , the image picker, the feedview and the feedviewmodel, I just have this class to upload pictures, my question is how can i improve it to upload multiple pictures at once.

Comment: If you’re trying to upload multiple items, it does sound like an array is the right approach. It’s just not clear to me from the included code where the items are coming from.

Comment: @jnpdx I have included the ImageUploader for more insight

Comment: This answer here works on a set number of images, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66987492/swiftui-upload-multiple-images-to-firebase i would like to achieve where users can post freely how many images they want with 10 being the limit.